# Apache server not responding. It just loads and then gives a timeout

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I have an apache2 server and have been trying to make it accessible to all but am unable to do so.
Here are the outputs:

```
$ netstat -plant | grep apache
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    15647/apache2
```

earlier it was :::80, but I changed it after seeing another post on serverfualt.com

```
$ ufw status
Status: inactive
```

```
$ service apache2 status
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-08-28 18:33:05 UTC; 16min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 15625 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 15647 (apache2)
      Tasks: 55 (limit: 4617)
     Memory: 12.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─15647 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─15648 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─15649 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Aug 28 18:33:05 localhost systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Aug 28 18:33:05 localhost systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

When I try to access it from browser, it just keeps on oading and after some point gives `site takes too long to respond` error.

Please help me resolve it. Also if any other output will be required, please inform me.

Comment: What is the domain name? What is the IP address?

Comment: I can not provide you the domain and the IP, can you tell me what you need it for? @MichaelHampton

Comment: How exactly did you connect to this server via browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already checked that the service is running.

Try to access your server from the server itself, in order to check if the service is accessible. A adequate command to check is telnet or curl, to be executed on the same machine the server is running:

```
$ telnet localhost 80
$ curl -v http://localhost
```

If this is working well, next is to check if the firewall on the server has opened port 80. Hint: `ufw` is just one type of firewall, there could be other programs as well. Please also check if another firewall ( for instance the one of your server provider) allows access to port 80.

Next step is to try the same, but to use the Public IP of the server. A command to know your public IP of the server is `echo $(curl -s ifconfig.me)`. Another way is to search for it in the output of `ip a`.

Finally you should check the DNS, eg. if your domain name points to the correct IP.